# Extracted Text from HTML Doc Into a List of Words

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup, I have extracted the comments on a web page from the html doc of said page. Using this code I have been able to print out the comments:

```js
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858560012/"
response = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor).open(url)
html_doc = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

def loop_until(text,first_elem):
  try: 
    text += first_elem.string
    if first_elem.next == first_elem.find_next('div'):
        return text
    else:
        return loop_until(text,first_elem.next.next)
  except TypeError:
      pass 
      
wordList = []

for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    next_elem = strong_tag.next_sibling
    print loop_until("", next_elem)
```

Now I need to take all the words from that selection and append them to wordList, how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your last line, use `append`

```
wordList.append(loop_until("", next_elem))
```